# Extract data from Log Files of different nature

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am not looking for any code in specific but an idea or a head start. I am trying to design an application with a User interface in which log files can be loaded.

These log files are of different formats and types. The data to be extracted also may vary with different files. I want to have one generic application to extract data from them. Thinking of Using some AI. Neural nets, Kalman, etc.

Sample1

```
A, B, C, D, E
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9,10
 ,11,12,13,14
```

in the above example I want to extract only column D and A. And column D should be extracted only when column A value exists.

Basically the log files are machine generated so there is no control on their formatting.

I have thought of creating an application in which a log file can be loaded. The required areas highlighted and then based on that the other similar types of log files are processed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to doing "generic" things, your best bet is to use interfaces. You will also want to use a design principle like DDD. So, you want to create an `ILogFile` interface. You will have different implementers of the `ILogFile` interface (an implementer class per log type, format or file). You will have a `service` (an application or domain service) that can work on an `ILogFile` interface to extract data from it and apply rules to it.

Although you cant control the format, I am assuming the log file's format is predictable.

Comment: This would still mean me implementing an interface for a new file type. Correct me please if I understood wrong. What I am trying for is to have a DIY. Definitely there is going to be a service which will be parsing the data in the background.

Comment: sounds like the main function in your application is file parsing. So, you want to define a file as an "entity" in your applicatioin's domain. A file entity will have properties like "Lines" and "characters". You also need a "rules" entity that can be persisted. Your domain service will apply a "rule" to a  file entity. This is a gross over simplification on my part. Depending on your need you could also do things like use the wrapper pattern for the rules. I hope I am actually answering your question here or at least saying things you havent already considered.

Comment: Your comments are helpful. I thought of things along the same line but I was wondering with this entity approach how generic or smart can the file parsing become.

Comment: The file parsing will be as smart as you make the granularity of the rules. That is, it could get very smart if the rules allow for very granular control